# The famous popup challenge

Tags: javascript

I used this script to redirect any user click on my page in to my youtube channel but what I want it's to activate this script or in other meaning to redirect the users in the first click on my page in every reload.Not every time the user will click he will be redirect to my channel

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.body.onclick= function()

{

window.open('https://www.youtube.com ', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=650, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
}</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.body.onclick = function() {
    window.open('https://www.youtube.com ', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=650, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
    document.body.onclick = null;
}
```

Comment: Sweet! I gotta remember that.

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
document.body.onclick= function()
{  
window.open('https://www.youtube.com ', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0,scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=650, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
document.body.onclick = undefined;
}
```

notice that I have removed the onclick event handler by assigning **undefined** to it after executing the code for the first time

Answer (score 1):

```
var handler = function() {
  window.open('https://www.youtube.com ', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=650, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
  document.body.removeEventListener('click', handler);
};

document.body.addEventListener('click', handler);
```

It is a better practice to manage event handlers using `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`. By doing so, other event handlers attached to `onclick` aren't overriden.